# How to turn off symmetry in texture paint mode

Tags: texture-painting, mirror

My question is very simple, I want to turn off mirroring in the texture paint mode (I'm using Blender 2.74 and I have tried a few older versions).
In tutorials I saw that there was a "Symmetry" tab, but I only have Brush, Texture, Texture Mask, Stroke, Curve, External and History.

Comment: Are you sure that in tutorials you saw `Symmetry` tab while in Texture Paint mode, but not in Sculpt mode ?

Comment: Yes I am, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMrFI-DWFxA So do i need to do something to get the tab or is there another way?

Comment: As is already stated in the answer, you should either wait for stable 2.75 or download release candidate of Blender (I didn't figure that out before because usually use stable versions) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Go Into Sculpt Mode And Look On The Left Side And Scroll Down Till You See Symmetry Lock And Click Any of The X,Y,Z SO They All Show Up White And Not Dark.

Answer (score 1):

This option is only available in the upcoming version, 2.75. It's not present in Blender 2.74 so there is no way to enable or disable it in this version.

You can either wait for the 2.75 release or if you want this option right now, download a release candidate version of Blender:

http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.75/